Navigation Stack does not pop views from stack
I've been working with navigation stacks to manage my app's state. After signing into the app, I expect it to render a conditional part displaying a tab view. However, this isn't happening even though the user session is no longer nil. I'm confused why I need to navigate back from the login view to see the updated navigation stack with the tab view.
In content view, the login screen and inside app is being conditionally shown based on if the user session is nil or not.
struct ContentView: View {
    // Uses EOPW to declare a property named viewModel of type AuthViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    ..
..
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            Group {
                if viewModel.userSession != nil {
                    TabView(selection: $selectedTab){
    
                } else {
// this appears if user session is nil. 
                    Landing_Page().onAppear(perform: {
                        print(viewModel.currentUser?.id ?? "none")
                    })
                }
            }
        } .environmentObject(registrationViewModel)
    }
}

the login view:
struct LoginView: View {
    @State var email = ""
    @State var password = ""
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                  // .. login TextField Code
                    
                    // ..
                    
                    
                    Button {
                        Task {
                            // here if successsful, it sets the user session to true, and should change the screen to the tab view based on the conditional.
                            try await viewModel.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)
                  
                        }
                    } label: {
                        
                        HStack {
                            Text("SIGN IN")
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32, height: 48)
                    }
                    .background(Color(.systemBlue))
                    .disabled(!formIsValid)
                    .opacity(formIsValid ? 1 : 0.5)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button{
                        dismiss()
                    }label: {
                        HStack(spacing: 2) {
                            Text("Don't have an account?")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                            Text("Sign Up")
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                    }
                }
                
                .alert(isPresented: $viewModel.showAlert) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Error"),
                          message: Text(viewModel.authError?.description ?? ""))
                }
                
                if viewModel.isLoading {
                    CustomProgressView()
                }
            }
    }
}


The default tab view cannot be inside a navigation stack. Each tab needs its own stack

@loremipsum Thank you so much. You are a life saver!
